# Logging in the C# classes using Electron-Log

Tags: c#, electron, asp.net-core-3.0, electron.net

In my **Asp.NET Core 3 Electron.NET** web application, I'm using **[Electron-Log](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-log)** npm package to carry out the logging.

I'm able to log in the script section like this:

```
const log = require('electron-log');

log.info('Hello, log');
log.warn('Some problem appears');
```

In the sample application, how could I use this to **log from a C# controller or any other C# class**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Electron-Log is used to record the log information of the `client`.

For the `code behind` in .net core, you can refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.1).